# How to decode hex data of DHCP relay packet with scapy?

Tags: python, networking, scapy, dhcp, packet-sniffers

I want to sniff DHCP packets from a DHCP relay on my DHCP server with scapy but I have a problem because the only part of interest to me is written in hex.

Is a way to force scapy to decode this part or another library to do that?

Below there is an example of a packet sniffed by scapy. The part I want to decode is the "data" under "Unknown DHCPv6 Option":

```
###[ Ethernet ]###
  dst= f4:cf:e2:4c:9c:ed
  src= 00:22:bd:f8:35:47
  type= 0x86dd
###[ IPv6 ]###
     version= 6L
     tc= 0L
     fl= 0L
     plen= 149
     nh= UDP
     hlim= 255
     src= 2001:db8:0:1::ee
     dst= 2001:db8:0:1::ed
###[ UDP ]###
        sport= dhcpv6_server
        dport= dhcpv6_server
        len= 149
        chksum= 0xd489
###[ DHCPv6 Relay Forward Message (Relay Agent/Server Message) ]###
           msgtype= RELAY-FORW
           hopcount= 0
           linkaddr= 2001:db8:0:1::e6
           peeraddr= fe80::f6cf:e2ff:fe11:7ef9
###[ Unknown DHCPv6 OPtion ]###
              optcode= RELAY_MSG
              optlen= 77
              data= '\x01\xed\t{\x00\x01\x00\n\x00\x03\x00\x01B\x00\x14\\U\xb3\x00\x06\x00\x04\x00\x17\x00\x18\x00\x08\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x19\x00)\xe2\x11~\xf9\x00\x00\x0e\x10\x00\x00\x15\x18\x00\x1a\x00\x19\x00\x00\x1c \x00\x00*00 \x01\x0b\xc80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
###[ DHCP6 Option - Relay Agent Remote-ID ]###
                 optcode= OPTION_REMOTE_ID
                 optlen= 14
                 enterprisenum= ciscoSystems
                 remoteid= '\x00\x03\x08\x00\x00"\xbd\xf85G'
###[ DHCP6 Interface-Id Option ]###
                    optcode= INTERFACE_ID
                    optlen= 4
                    ifaceid= '\t\x01\x00\n'
```

when I do `packet[DHCP6OptUnknown].getfieldval(data)` It returns

`'\x01\xed\t{\x00\x01\x00\n\x00\x03\x00\x01B\x00\x14\\U\xb3\x00\x06\x00\x04\x00\x17\x00\x18\x00\x08\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x19\x00)\xe2\x11~\xf9\x00\x00\x0e\x10\x00\x00\x15\x18\x00\x1a\x00\x19\x00\x00\x1c \x00\x00*00 \x01\x0b\xc80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'`

This is the data I want, and inside I would like to get the Prefix delegation sent by the server.

Thanks in advance for your help !

Ps: sorry for my poor english :)

**EDIT :** 
After patching a DHCP relay packet looks like this :

```
###[ Ethernet ]###
  dst= 00:22:bd:f8:35:47
  src= f4:cf:e2:4c:9c:ed
  type= 0x86dd
###[ IPv6 ]###
     version= 6L
     tc= 0L
     fl= 0L
     plen= 192
     nh= UDP
     hlim= 64
     src= 2001:db8:0:1::ed
     dst= 2001:db8:0:1::ee
###[ UDP ]###
        sport= dhcpv6_server
        dport= dhcpv6_server
        len= 192
        chksum= 0x26dc
###[ DHCPv6 Relay Reply Message (Relay Agent/Server Message) ]###
           msgtype= RELAY-REPL
           hopcount= 0
           linkaddr= 2001:db8:0:1::e6
           peeraddr= fe80::f6cf:e2ff:fe11:7ef9
###[ DHCP6 Interface-Id Option ]###
              optcode= INTERFACE_ID
              optlen= 4
              ifaceid= '\t\x01\x00\n'
###[ DHCP6 Relay Message Option ]###
                 optcode= RELAY_MSG
                 optlen= 138
###[ DHCPv6 Reply Message ]###
                    msgtype= REPLY
                    trid= 0x8bcc55
###[ DHCP6 Option - Identity Association for Prefix Delegation ]###
                       optcode= OPTION_IA_PD
                       optlen= 41
                       iaid= 3792797433
                       T1= 3600
                       T2= 7200
                       \iapdopt\
                        |###[ DHCP6 Option - IA_PD Prefix option ]###
                        |  optcode= OPTION_IAPREFIX
                        |  optlen= 25
                        |  preflft= 4500
                        |  validlft= 7200
                        |  plen= 48
                        |  prefix= 2001:db8:3000::
                        |  iaprefopts= ''
###[ DHCP6 Client Identifier Option ]###
                          optcode= CLIENTID
                          optlen= 10
                          \duid\
                           |###[ DUID - Based on Link-layer Address ]###
                           |  type= Link-layer Address
                           |  hwtype= Ethernet (10Mb)
                           |  lladdr= 42:00:14:xx:xx:xx
###[ DHCP6 Server Identifier Option ]###
                             optcode= SERVERID
                             optlen= 14
                             \duid\
                              |###[ DUID - Link-layer address plus time ]###
                              |  type= Link-layer address plus time
                              |  hwtype= Ethernet (10Mb)
                              |  timeval= Tue, 24 Mar 2015 03:09:53 +0000 (1427166593)
                              |  lladdr= f4:cf:e2:4c:9c:ed
###[ DHCP6 Preference Option ]###
                                optcode= PREFERENCE
                                optlen= 1
                                prefval= 255
###[ DHCP6 Option - DNS Recursive Name Server ]###
                                   optcode= DNS Recursive Name Server Option
                                   optlen= 32
                                   dnsservers= [ 2001:db8:401::3, 2001:db8:1::16 ]
###[ DHCP6 Option - Domain Search List option ]###
                                      optcode= Domain Search List option
                                      optlen= 12
                                      dnsdomains= ['foo.net']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many time, I find this patch : http://bb.secdev.org/scapy/pull-request/82/dhcpv6-relay-reply-message-relay-agent/diff#chg-scapy/layers/dhcp6.py and it works for me. All the packet is decoded !

Comment: Interesting! I'll have a look.

Comment: Hi, I have posted a comment on that issue. Could you provide a capture file of the traffic you have? That would really help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks! Can you also add the output of `str(packet)`?